# What is the best option, transaction locking for distributed systems?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

I am using NHibernate and really new to that.  My dilemna is when
I open a web browser, it shows the table data.  Meantime another person opens another web browser and hence read the existing data from the database.

Meantime, I make changes in the my pages and save.  And the user save his changes afterwards.  When I reload the page, I no more find my data, but that of the user, i.e his was the latest and mine were replaced.

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: This question might be of some interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364265/what-is-the-best-default-transaction-isolation-level-for-an-erp-if-any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement optimistic concurrency control: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic

The most performant way is adding a `<version>` to your entities (see http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version)

Comment: Thanks for replying. How can I use isolation?